# Swapping elements of char array in C

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
char *sort(char *string){ //shell-sort
    int lnght = length(string) - 1; // length is my own function
    int gap = lnght / 2;
    while (gap > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lnght; i++)
        {
            int j = i + gap;
            int tmp =(int)string[j];
            while (j >= gap && tmp > (int)string[j - gap])
            {
                string[j] = string[j - gap]; // code fails here
                j -= gap;
            }
            string[j] = (char)tmp; // and here as well
        }
        if (gap == 2){
            gap = 1;
        }
        else{
            gap /= 2.2;
        }
    }
    return string;
}
```

The code should sort (shell-sort) the characters in the string, given the ordinal value (ASCII value). Even though the code is pretty simple, it still fails at lines I've commented - segmentation fault. I've spent plenty of time with this code and still can't find the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "fails"?

Comment: `gap /= 2.2;` ? Seriously ?

Comment: Seems pretty clear you're exceeding your array bounds.

Comment: @dandan78 Segmentation fault

Comment: @PaulR Computing the gap in shell-sort is the best with 2.2 value instead of 2. I am aware what it does given that the value is integer

Comment: @machineyearning I guess you're right (given the error I get), but the code seems ok to me.

Comment: @Croolman I recommend refactoring your code to simplify your indexing math. Can you post the code for the `length` function? Usually the practice is to pass the length around as a parameter with the array.

Comment: @Croolman Have you tried running in a debugger? Just reading code isn't the best way to find errors. Also, update your question to clarify what you mean by 'fails'.

Comment: @dandan78 I ve tried. That's how I know I ve 'violated the laws of memory'

Comment: how do you call the function? something like `sort("test");`?

Comment: @machineyearning There's nothing special about that function, the problem doesnt lie there. I am aware of that practise as such, but can't do it that way.

Comment: @mch Nope. `char *str = "test string"; sort(str);` I call it as an argument of printf function, so it is printed out directly.

Comment: @Croolman Okay, so you know which lines it crashes on. You also probably know that a segmentation fault means you are probably accessing memory that does not 'belong' to you. Have you inspected your indexes? They are likely not what you expect them to be...

Comment: @dandan78 I've checked the indexes while debugging. It fails right in the first round with all indexes being in correct ranges. Everything seems to be just right.

Comment: @Croolman For future reference, all of the information you gave in answer to the comments written by me and the others should've been in your question to begin with. That's in case you're wondering why you have 3 close votes and 2 downvotes.

Comment: @dandan78 Thanks, I'll think of that next time I post the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you say in comment , you call our function like this -

```
 char *str = "test string";
 sort(str);
```

String literal is in read-only memory and creates a pointer `str` to that, thus it *cannot be modified* , and your function modifies it . Therefore ,it can result in segmentation fault .

Declare like this -

```
 char str[] = "test string";
```

Comment: You're right. I've never thought of that. That is absolutely working.

Comment: Great answer, however I think he will also have problems with array bounds based on my analysis below.

Comment: @machineyearning  Yes , he has to take your points also in account or else OP may get undefined behaviour as a gift :)

Answer (score 2):

In situations like this look at your statements not so much as executable code, but as mathematical boundary conditions. I've replaced the monstrous name `lnght` with `length` for readability purposes.

Here are the relevant conditions that affect the value of `j` when entering the `while` loop, relative to the length.

```
i < length;
gap = length / 2;
j = i + gap;
```

Now we plug in a value. Consider the case where `length == 10`. Then presumably the maximum index in your array is `9` which is also the highest value that `i` can take on.

Then we also have that `gap == 5` and so after entering the `while` loop `j == i + gap == 9 + 5`. Clearly `9 + 5 > 10`. The rest is left as an exercise to the programmer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will never happen, considering that starting position of i is 0 and gap is maximum, after one loop the gap is divided by 2 and i is incremented by 1. So it cant exceed the range of the array.

Comment: That's not true, gap isn't modified until after the `for` loop terminates, meaning `i` has already taken on every value from `0 .. length - 1`. Neither is `gap` the maximum of `i`, as clearly stated in your `for` loop logic `for (int i = 0; i < lnght; i++)`

Comment: @Croolman even if you had everything right here, spending a long time thinking about indexing arrays and their boundaries is the most dire curse of C/C++. I would strongly suggest you get in the habit of keeping your indexing logic as simple as possible in order to avoid little one-off bugs etc. It's not a problem with you as a programmer, it's a language design flaw ("feature"). Unfortunately the best way to deal with it is to only touch the indexes when absolutely necessary. Encapsulate indexing logic in reusable functions so you don't make little mistakes that everyone makes.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Sorry, my fault. I'll have to look into it. ... Indexes are for sure a lil bit tricky think and in this example I use them a lot, althought sometimes it is hard to live without them, but I get you.

Answer (score 1):

How do you test your function? With a static string (i.e. char *buffer = "test string";) ?

Because on first loop at least j and j-gap should be inside the string boundaries. So if you get a segfault I guess it is because of a bad string (statics can't be modified).

Replacing length() by strlen() and calling it with a well-created test string lead me to a valid result:
"adgfbce" → "gfedcba"